# Error with gedit can't save any file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gedit

```
meraj@meraj-SATELLITE-C850-A785:~$ sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

(gedit:16243): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

whenever I save the file in gedit it is not saved what should I do?

I have ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Hm, does it happen, when you don't invoke `sudo`? I suppose, it might have to do with user switching. AFAIK, you shouldn't use `sudo` for graphical applications, use `gksudo` instead. Here's almost exact answer to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application

Comment: Sorry, but problem exist. Thanks for support
meraj@meraj-SATELLITE-C850-A785:/var/www/html$ gksudo gedit meraj.php

(gedit:17472): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:17472): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
meraj@meraj-SATELLITE-C850-A785:/var/www/html$

Comment: Hm. Did you manually tweak your graphical environment? (installed/removed something)? Do you have Gnome 3 installed or something else?

Comment: One more thing. Do those Gtk-WARNINGs prevent you from saving your file? I thought, they shouldn't be critical - usually it curses, but works.

Answer (score 2):

**What to do?**

You shouldn't use `sudo` for graphical applications, such as `gedit`. [Use `gksudo` instead.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application)

**What's causing the error**

I'm not sure. Apparently, the reason of error you get is that `gedit` is trying to invoke `SessionManager`'s [Inhibit](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#id344989) method via [D-bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/).

If normal applications can connect to dbus, they should have some config files in `/usr/share/dbus-1`. I expected them to be `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.SessionManager.service` or `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.gnome.SessionManager.service`. On my Debian machine I can't find any of them.

So, my guess is `gnome-session` doesn't need a dbus `.session` file as it's not a normal application. In fact, it is itself responsible for starting the per-session instance of dbus. But the per-session instance of dbus is in fact per-user per-session, so it can't interact with graphical application running under different user than you (and root user, running `sudo gedit`, is different than you).

Answer (score -1):

```
$ gksudo gedit <etc/ path>
```

This will work.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! This unfortunately doesn’t add anything which isn’t already mentioned in the existing answer...